# Binding more processes than cpus error in SLURM openmpi

Tags: mpi, slurm, openmpi, sbatch

I am trying to run a job that uses explicit message passing between nodes on SLURM (i.e. not just running parallel jobs) but am getting a recurring error that "a request was made to bind to that would result in binding more processes than cpus on a resource". Briefly, my code requires sending an array of parameters across 128 nodes, calculating a likelihood of those parameters, and gathering the sum of those likelihood values back to the root node. I got the error when executing the code using the following sbatch file:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=linesearch
#SBATCH --output=ls_%j.txt
#SBATCH --nodes=16
#SBATCH --ntasks-per-node=16
#SBATCH --partition=broadwl
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=2000
#SBATCH --time=18:00:00

# Load the default OpenMPI module.
module load openmpi

mpiexec -N 8 ./linesearch
```

I thought that using `-N 8` would explicitly assign 8 processes-per-node to 16 `--ntasks-per-node`. I thought that using this method, which is an inefficient use of computer processing space, would reduce this error following a response to a different overflow thread, but it didn't resolve the issue.

The full error message, if useful, is as follows:

```
A request was made to bind to that would result in binding more
processes than cpus on a resource:

   Bind to:     NONE:IF-SUPPORTED
   Node:        XXXXXX
   #processes:  4
   #cpus:       3

You can override this protection by adding the "overload-allowed"
option to your binding directive.
```

The processes that I'm executing can be memory intensive, so I don't want to necessarily use the overload override in the risk of jobs terminating after exhausting allocation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that I was loading module openmpi v2.0.1 [retired]. However, changing the sbatch file to bind to socket with only `-np 128` tasks resolved this issue

sbatch file:

```
#!/bin/bash

#SBATCH --job-name=linesearch
#SBATCH --output=ls_%j.txt
#SBATCH --nodes=16
#SBATCH --ntasks=128
#SBATCH --partition=broadwl
#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=2000
#SBATCH --time=18:00:00

# Load the default OpenMPI module.
module load openmpi

mpiexec -np 128 ./execs/linesearch $1 $2
```

An alternative solution is to use `--bind-to core --map-by core` in the `mpiexec` statement to bind each process to a core